# Problem with Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to compute the Fourier expansion coefficients by `Integrate`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
A = 0.47247194112569824`;
\[Delta]y = 0.02752805887430132`;
h = 7.633623089246928`;

G = 2 \[Pi]/h;
xc = -A*Cos[(2 \[Pi])/h y] + \[Delta]y;
bp = E^(n G xc);
Integrate[1/h bp E^(-M1 I  G y), {y, -h/2, h/2}
```

It seems `Integrate` cannot solve this problem. What can I do to get the correct result? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `Integrate` for such cases. Use dedicated `Fourier*` functions, like [`FourierTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html), [`FourierCosTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCosTransform.html), [`FourierCosCoefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCosCoefficient.html) ... Please try them, then edit the question with the code if you still encounter problems.

Comment: are $n$ and $M1$ supposed to be integers? And it is better to use exact numbers with `Integrate`

Comment: @Domen Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, both `n` and `M1` are integers.